# Scrapy use private proxy

Tags: python, proxy, scrapy, squid

I am using customly configured VM to act as a proxy server (via squid) and now I try to use it for my scraper. I am using [scrapy-rotating-proxies](https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/scrapy-rotating-proxies) to rotate trought my ip list definition but the problem is that my proxy is treated as DEAD right on the first attempt even thought I have verified that the proxy address is alive and is working just fine (I tested it by setting a proxy in firefox and tried to browse both `http` and `https` web pages. The proxy server is passwordless for testing purposes

scrapy settings

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    "scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware": None,
    "scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware": None,
    "scrapy_fake_useragent.middleware.RandomUserAgentMiddleware": 400,
    "scrapy_fake_useragent.middleware.RetryUserAgentMiddleware": 401,
    "rotating_proxies.middlewares.RotatingProxyMiddleware": 610,
    "rotating_proxies.middlewares.BanDetectionMiddleware": 620,
}

ROTATING_PROXY_LIST = ["X.X.X.X:3128"]
```

scrapy logs

```
2022-12-02 13:31:22 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2022-12-02 13:31:22 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-12-02 13:31:22 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2022-12-02 13:31:22 [rotating_proxies.middlewares] INFO: Proxies(good: 0, dead: 0, unchecked: 1, reanimated: 0, mean backoff time: 0s)
2022-12-02 13:31:32 [rotating_proxies.expire] DEBUG: Proxy <http://X.X.X.X:3128> is DEAD
2022-12-02 13:31:32 [rotating_proxies.middlewares] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.johnlewis.com/header/api/config> with another proxy (failed 1 times, max retries: 5)
2022-12-02 13:31:32 [rotating_proxies.middlewares] WARNING: No proxies available; marking all proxies as unchecked
```

Settings I have changed for squid

```
http_access allow all
via off
forwarded_for delete
```

Please advice what can be the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   "scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware": None,
   "scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware": None,
```

These middlewares was the issue, I cannot explain why scrapy was able to process my requests without proxies while having these middlewares enabled but after disabling them I was able to run scrapy using my proxies.